# Excel VBA .click event not working with <a> tag

Tags: excel, vba, href

I'm trying to automate logging into a website to get my account balance.

The .click event on the login button is not working. I feel I'm missing something simple.

```
    Sub test()

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    my_url = "https://www.synchronycredit.com/eSecurity/Login/login.action?clientId=google&accountType=plcc&langId=en"

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate my_url
        .Top = 50
        .Left = 530
        .Height = 400
        .Width = 400

    Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    End With


    IE.document.getElementById("loginUserID").Value = "userNameHere"
    IE.document.getElementById("loginPassword").Value = "passWordHere"


    IE.document.getElementByID("secLoginBtn").Click

    Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Here is the code from the website:

```
<a tabindex="0" title="Login to your account" id="secLoginBtn" role="button" style="cursor: pointer;" data-reason="login:start:submit" onclick="javascript:setRememberMeFlag('rememUID');" data-type="button" class="ADAbtn btn secLoginBtn secureLockImg ensightenmEvent">

                                        <img class="pull-left" src="/essimages/cs/groups/ess_webasset/generic/@common/en/brandimages/044828.png" alt="">
                                    Secure Login</a>
```

Comment: I think you need to fire the `onclick="javascript:setRememberMeFlag('rememUID')` event... with a quick google you'll find a fair few other questions/answers about what you want to do. See how you go with that.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all:**
Always use `Option Explicit` as first line in **every** VBA module.

To solve your problem you need first to trigger the keypress events for the input fields. After entering the values you can click the submit button.

**First line:**

```
Option Explicit
```

**Main makro:**

```
Sub test()

Dim browser As Object
Dim url As String
Dim nodeUserName As Object
Dim nodePassWord As Object
Dim nodeSubmitButton As Object
Dim domDoc As Object
Dim userName As String
Dim passWord As String

  userName = "Your Name"
  passWord = "YourPassword"

  Set browser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  url = "https://www.synchronycredit.com/eSecurity/Login/login.action?clientId=google&accountType=plcc&langId=en"

  'Initialize Internet Explorer, set visibility,
  'call URL and wait until page is fully loaded
  Set browser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  browser.Visible = True
  browser.navigate url
  browser.Top = 50
  browser.Left = 530
  browser.Height = 400
  browser.Width = 400
  Do Until browser.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
  Set domDoc = browser.document

  Set nodeUserName = domDoc.getElementByID("loginUserID")
  Call TriggerEvent(domDoc, nodeUserName, "onKeypress")
  nodeUserName.Value = userName

  Set nodePassWord = domDoc.getElementByID("loginPassword")
  Call TriggerEvent(domDoc, nodePassWord, "onKeypress")
  nodePassWord.Value = passWord

  Set nodeSubmitButton = domDoc.getElementByID("secLoginBtn")
  nodeSubmitButton.Click

End Sub
```

**Subroutine to trigger a html event:**

```
Private Sub TriggerEvent(htmlDocument As Object, htmlElementWithEvent As Object, eventType As String)

  Dim theEvent As Object

  htmlElementWithEvent.Focus
  Set theEvent = htmlDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
  theEvent.initEvent eventType, True, False
  htmlElementWithEvent.dispatchEvent theEvent
End Sub
```